# (Crawling) How to get tweet sort date from oldest

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler

I use python, I have been tried tweepy but I get sort from newest and it limited, just can crawl data last 1 week.
So I looking for new way, I find this https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python . This library allow me to get old tweet more than 1 week, but I don't find a way to get list tweet from the oldest too. This library also start from the newest tweet first.

please.. is there anyone know how to crawl data from twitter sort from the oldest tweet?

Comment: Crawl the https://m.twitter.com

Comment: @stamaimer what do you mean?